# Unable to Tweet using create_tweet()

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've provided the key, secret key & tokens for my Twitter Dev account -

```
nclient = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=consumer_key, consumer_secret=consumer_sec_key,
                    access_token=auth.access_token, access_token_secret=auth.access_token_secret)
```

And then I tried Tweeting a new Tweet -

```
new_tweet = nclient.create_tweet("First tweet!")
```

It gives me the below error -

```
TypeError: create_tweet() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

When I try running the below command -

```
new_tweet = nclient.create_tweet(text = "First tweet!")
```

It gives me the below error -

```
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
```

Please help me with a resolution for this issue.

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: some functions uses named argument - like `create_tweet(text=...)` - and they will not work if you send it as `create_tweet(...)`. And `403` can means that you have wrong API keys. Or maybe module is old and it doesn't work with newest API. You could create minimal working code so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: Did you set read and write permissions on your app before generating the access token? Are you sure all 4 auth values are correct? Is your app a part of a project in the Twitter App Dashboard?

Comment: @AndyPiper -  I have "Read and Write (Read + Post Tweets and profile information)" permissions set on my app -

Comment: @furas - I tested API keys for other commands (user1 = api.get_user(screen_name = 'SpaceX')) and those are working fine.

Comment: @furas - Here is the complete error for 1st command - ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-096bf56c3efc> in <module>
----> 1 new_tweet = nclient.create_tweet("First tweet!")

TypeError: create_tweet() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @furas - I'm unable to put the complete error for "Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
" as it is too long and not allowed here

Comment: @furas - Understood. I'll follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revoked the previous keys & tokens from the Twitter app and regenerated those. Then I used it in the below commands and now I'm able to tweet, delete the tweet and do other activities.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
new_tweet = api.update_status(status = 'First tweet from #python !') #post a tweet
new_tweet.destroy() # delete a tweet
```

Thank you all for the help provided!

Answer (score 3):

The `TypeError` is because `Client.create_tweet` doesn't accept `text` as a positional argument. The 1 positional argument being referred to in the error is `self`.

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941092/unable-to-tweet-using-create-tweet#comment123638635_69941092), you're very likely using credentials that don't have the write permission. If you have already given your app the write permission, you need to regenerate your credentials afterwards and use those new credentials.

See [the FAQ section on this in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.3.0/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-401-unauthorized-error).

If that's not the issue, then make sure you're not using a standalone app. [Twitter API v2 requires that you use a Project](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview).