# why do i get Client.create_tweet() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: tweepy, chatgpt-api

```
import tweepy 
import keys
import openai

openai.api_key = keys.aiapikey
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "give me best tweet of the day please"},])
        
client=tweepy.Client(consumer_key=keys.api,
                     consumer_secret=keys.apisecret,
                     access_token=keys.accesstoken,
                     access_token_secret=keys.accesssecret)
                     
client.create_tweet(response)
```

is there another way to say create_tweet that doesnt give 2 pos arguments?

code in the above box

Comment: are you sure, that's the correct position in the code, the error points to? Because for that code the error message doesn't make any sense, because you are only passing one argument. Do you have any other calls to `create_tweet` in your code?

Comment: no, that is my entire code edit: client.create_tweet(response) is the specific line it throws a tantrum about

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to Tweet using create\_tweet()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941092/unable-to-tweet-using-create-tweet)

Comment: nup doesnt work

Comment: So you have tried `create_tweet(text = "...")` and it still does throw the same error? Doubt that ...

Answer (score 0):

This is might be a bug in tweepy, but you can fix it by calling the function like this

```
client.create_tweet(text=response)
```

So your code will be

```
import tweepy 
import keys
import openai

openai.api_key = keys.aiapikey
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "give me best tweet of the day please"},])
    
client=tweepy.Client(consumer_key=keys.api,
                 consumer_secret=keys.apisecret,
                 access_token=keys.accesstoken,
                 access_token_secret=keys.accesssecret)
                 
client.create_tweet(text=response)
```